# SQL subset sum negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subset-sum

I have a table valued function that return the set of rows that matches a given sum, It works fine with positive values but not with negatives one.

Can someone modify this function to work with both positive and negative values (price field)

The function take a table with decimal values, then return the first combination of rows that match a given sum in the parameter :

For example if the @psum = 9 and the given table below :

```
n   id  price
1   1   4.00
2   2   4.00
3   3   5.00
4   4   6.00
5   5   8.00
```

The out put is :

```
select * from SubsetSum2(9)

n   id  price
3   3   5.00
2   2   4.00

alter FUNCTION [dbo].[SubsetSum2](@psum int )  
RETURNS  @tt table  (n int,id int, price numeric(20,2))
AS  
BEGIN

declare @t table  (n int IDENTITY(1,1), id int,  price numeric(20,2))
insert into @t -- note asc order of book prices

select  1, 4 union all
select  2, 4 union all
select  3, 5 union all
select  4, 6 union all
select  5, 8 

declare @rows int, @p numeric(20,2), @sum numeric(20,2) set @sum= 9
delete from @t where price>@sum
set @p=(select sum(price) from @t)

if @p>= @sum
begin --1
set @rows=(select max(n) from @t)
declare @n int, @s numeric(20,2)
set @n=@rows+1 set @s=0
while 0=0
begin --2
while @n>1
begin --3
set @n=@n-1
if @s+(select price from @t where n=@n)<=@sum
and @s+(select sum(price) from @t where n<=@n)>=@sum
begin --4
set @s=@s+(select price from @t where n=@n)
insert into @tt select n, id, price from @t where n=@n
if @s=@sum return ; 
end --4
end  --3
set @n=(select min(n) from @tt)
set @s=@s-(select price from @tt where n=@n)
delete from @tt where n=@n
if @s=0 and (select sum(price) from @t where n<@n)<@sum break
end --2
end --1

return
END
```

Comment: Please save us time by telling us what the function does vs. what it should do. with some output examples.

Comment: `-5+5+5+4 = 9` is this not correct? do you want your negative amounts to be treated as positive?

Comment: yes this is correct, but the function doesn't work with that example.

Comment: given `select  2, -5 union all` instead of `select  2, 4 union all` what output do you expect? should the "combination" always be in sequence(next in line)?

Comment: in that case the expected result is :
n   id  price | 3   3   5.00 | 1   1   4.00

No matter of the order of combination

Answer (score -1):

Use Absolute function ABS(Price) for treating the negatives as positives

Comment: I don't want to treat négative as positive